# Is mongoose populate() function execute separately for each related documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-populate

I have following models.

User model

- name
- email

Category model

- name
- createdById (references User model)

A Category is created by a user and a user can have multiple categories created by him/she.
Mine scenario is to retrieve all categories with createdBy User object inside each category document.

```
let categories = await CategoryModel.find({})
      .populate("createdById", "_id name email", "User")
      .exec();
```

Expected Result

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5fb239eff11d915fb0f8f9ff",
        "name": "Vehicle",
        "createdById": {
            "_id": "53f439eff11f215fb0f8f94f",
            "name": "ABC Man",
            "email": "......"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5fb239eff11d915fb0f8f1fh",
        "name": "Fruits",
        "createdById": {
            "_id": "53f439eff31f21efb0q8f94f",
            "name": "XYZ Man",
            "email": "......"
        }
    },
    {
        "_id": "5fb239effe4td915fb0f8f1fh",
        "name": "Vegetables",
        "createdById": {
            "_id": "53f439eff31f21efbf4af94f",
            "name": "BBC Man",
            "email": "......"
        }
    }
]
```

So my question is

1. whether mongoose separately execute query for getting createdById object on each iteration of category document
2. or mongoose first retrieve all the category documents first and then extract createdById property value from each category document and keep into array. Array then executed for getting all users detail with one query (using $in operator). Mapping user back into each category document.

Comment: Mongoose performs the operation locally, so it will use multiple $in operator to perform the populate. Meaning, it will first query to get your above results, then it will do another query on your  createdById collection e.g. createdById.find({ id: { "$in": [ array of ids ]}})

Comment: use mongoose.set('debug',true) to see what's going on behind the scene.

Comment: Thankyou for quick reply. Is there any way to find out how such operation processing background?

Comment: Thankyou @SomeoneSpecial. You are right. Please add your comment in answer section so i can mark as answer